# Windows Firewall is blocking connection sharing (ICS)

Tags: windows-xp, home-networking, windows-firewall, connection-sharing

How do I keep Windows Firewall from blocking Internet Connection Sharing, or just permanently disable Windows Firewall?  Everytime I plug in a computer into my network card Windows Firewall turns itself back on, blocking the connection, until I manually go into the properties for the new connection (new name, or old) and disable Windows Firewall.

I am using Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) to share my internet connection with computers I plug into it.  I disabled Windows Firewall with start->run->firewall.cpl - but that is IGNORED by Windows.

I thought of disabling the service, but the service is called "Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing."  Windows apparently locked them together.  I need ICS, obviously.

My computer: Windows XP SP3 w/all updates. Comodo Internet Security (firewall).

Once I told Comodo to allow connections from 192.168.0.1-192.168.255.255, it has never blocked the internet on computers I plug in.  Windows firewall needs KILLED PERMANENTLY.)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Re: OS Version: "Windows XP SP3 w/all updates" isn't specific enough?

Comment: to tag a user or respond to his/hers comment/post, use the @symbol followed by their name, similar to Twitter.

Comment: @Moab: see @CraigB's comment. just notifying you. :-)